# Windows Authentication LAN & WAN

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, wan

I use windows authentication with IIS and C#. In my global.asax i get the user name to define rights (profile and rights are in a mysql Database). It s working well but i need now to use it fron wan. We use a Firewall Netasq wich provide a VPN SSL whith LDAP authentication. Behind the firewal call an url whith in parameter the name of the authentified user (something like SSO).

What's the best way to authorize wan user to access site : custom authentication provider, using role.

thank by advance.

Answer (score 0):

At this point the solution i have found is :

Allow access to unauthenticated user in my web.config,
Use tow domain name with same directory : 1 that work with windows authentication, 1 with anonymous access,

My netasq call the unauthenticated site with in the url an HTTP_NETASQ_USER witch is the login.

In my global.asax (session start) i use this url param to identify user if the request came from the Netasq IP. Otherwise i use the windows login.

I think there is better ways but it work.